# Autodesk Forge - How to stop recoloring of object when selected

Tags: autodesk-forge

Our elements are color coded so when a user selects one we just want to isolate it in the views (which works as expected) BUT we don't want it to change to the selection color - where can we control this?

Answer (score 0):

Use selection event to find which object has been selected, cancel the selection and isolate the selected dbId, is this the behavior you are looking for?

AutodeskNamespace("Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension");

```
Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Basic = function (viewer, options) {

  Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.call(this, viewer, options);

  var _this = this;

  _this.load = function () {

    console.log('LOAD')

    viewer.addEventListener(
        Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, function(e) {

            //console.log(e)

            if(e.selections.length) {
                var dbId = e.selections[0].dbIdArray[0]
                viewer.select([])
                viewer.isolate(dbId)
            }
        })


    return true;
  };

  _this.unload = function () {

    Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.unregisterExtension(
      "Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Basic");

    return true;
  };
};

Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Basic.prototype =
  Object.create(Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.prototype);

Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Basic.prototype.constructor =
  Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Basic;

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension(
  "Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Basic",
  Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Basic);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to keep the selection just not make it blue in the UI, you can change the selection material's opacity to see-through:

```
viewer.impl.selectionMaterialBase.opacity = 0;
viewer.impl.selectionMaterialTop.opacity = 0;
```

Now when you click on an object it won't turn blue.

Comment: Yeah - still want it with the exact opacity it had before: just not changing the color. Idea is that we will isolate it in the view (i.e. make other objects translucent instead

Comment: When you select an object then an extra layer of selection color is added on top with the opacity that the above code is modifying. So this code is just removing the selection color on top. If the selection color was the same as the object itself then I don't think it would make any difference in the appearance of the selected object - so not sure what you mean by wanting to keep the exact same opacity. Philippe's code above shows how to do an isolate on the selected object so that the non-selected ones fade into the background. Is that not good enough?

Comment: My Mistake - looks like it will do the job perfectly. Thanks. Ill get my programmers to give it a go.