# How can you change the Viewer's selection color?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I see that the viewer has a MeshPhongMaterial that it looks like it applies to scene objects that you click, but when I try to change the RGB values of this, it does nothing. So, how do you change the selection color in the viewer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the code is what you are looking for. Please check if it helps.

```
viewer.impl.setSelectionColor(new THREE.Color(1,0,0))
```

In addition, another SO post might be also interesting to you:
[Autodesk Forge - How to stop recoloring of object when selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39985115/autodesk-forge-how-to-stop-recoloring-of-object-when-selected)

[image]

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you. Is there a reason things like this aren't in the documentation?

Comment: sorry, it is a known issue with documentation on *.impl functions. As they are not officially exposed, so not documented yet. But you can still use them if needed.

Comment: I think more documentation and the ability to search your docs would very much help people leverage the platform better. It is very annoying not to be able to search through it.